# Excel always adds wrong time format after PHPExcel script

Tags: phpexcel

I have a script using PHPExcel framework and everything is working perfectly fine except for one big issue when calculating the sum of a column.

It works and the right number is in the cell, the only thing is that when I run the script (and I checked the Excel file I uploaded, no wrong formats there) it converts my TIME cell into a DD.MM.YYY HH:MM cell which corrupts my sum equation.

Whenever I change the field types (formats) manually in Excel, the sum is right and everything works.

What can I do to find and fix the problem?

Comment: The styling of a cell has absolutely no bearing on any calculation using the data in that cell..... please provide specifics of your problem - the actual data in the cell, the formula that you're using - etc. Unless you can actually describe the problem in detail, I can't offer any advice on how to fix it

Comment: Although the work is already done using something else than a excel table (which is probably the best for everything done in browsers), the problem was that whenever I ran the script which calculated every cell it had to, excel did overwrite the styling of this cell. Now I used the styling parameters that PHPExcel provides but this didn't help. I guess it's just Microsoft and it's excel. It was formatting a cell containing a date and another containing a price to something completly wrong. I don't remember the exact formats but I think this describes it best.

Comment: Does the original spreadsheet cell actually contain a formatted date string ("21.05.2014 17:40") or an Excel timestamp value (41780.7361111111)? Note that a field type is not a format, they're totally different things

Comment: It contained a decimal number for the price and the actual formated date string. Also, the right cell formats where set in advance to uploading the excel file to the script. Ok, so I called it format but ment field type. Sorry.

Comment: Assuming that this is an actual Excel format file, then then PHPExcel should be treating any string as a string, and not changing it in any way; if it's a csv format file (regardless of file extension) then the default value binder will convert formatted strings that match a date/time pattern to an excel timestamp, and format the cell as a date/time cell... you can avoid this behaviour by using a custom binder for csv files when loading